# iWork Pages Converting to PDF

Tags: pdf, pages, iwork

I am using a template from Pages for a document. When I convert it to PDF, it loses its style and font.

I've tried exporting it as a PDF as well as printing it as a PDF.

Any suggestions on how I could keep its format and font intact when conveying it to PDF?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What sort of styling is gone wrong when converting to PDF? And which version of iWork and Mac are you running atm?

From experience (under 10.6) I can only say never to have had problems with converting to PDF or printing as PDF. If your iWork is messed up, you may want to consider reinstalling. (Use CleanApp for that) or install a newer version (do you have iWork '09? have you fully updated it?).

Comment: Definitely reinstall and update. I'd exported probably 1000s upon 1000s of PDFs from Pages and have never once had any weird formatting issues like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting a normal file (so, no images, bold-fonts, font-types,...) just two lines with a different font-size and some additional taps. Can you export these files as PDF and keeping the style and layout?

An alternative could be [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com). An online-converting tool. But I can suggest the same as Max Z., try reïnstalling the software!